# Is it safe to use Apache commons-io IOUtils.closeQuietly?

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-io

Is this code

```
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));
    try {
        bw.write("test");
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(bw);
    }
```

safe or not? As far as I understand when we close a BufferedWriter it will flush its buffer to the underlying stream and may fail due to an error. But IOUtils.closeQuietly API says that any exceptions will be ignored.

Is it possible a data loss will go unnoticed due to IOUtils.closeQuietly?

Comment: Not an answer, but [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement will eliminate most needs for using `IOUtils.closeQuietly`.

Comment: Good answer, but this feature is new in Java 7. If you're stuck using Java 6 for some reason (e.g. older Android versions) then `closeQuietly()` is still the way to go.

Comment: IOUtils.closeQuietly HAS BEEN DEPRECATED NOW use try with resource instead.

Comment: closeQuietly(..) is still necessary if the close() method of the resource throws an checked exception. In this case try-with-resources can't be used as an exception on close() will bubble up.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The code should look like this regarding to the javadoc of `closeQuietly()`:

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;

try {
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));
    bw.write("test");
    bw.flush(); // you can omit this if you don't care about errors while flushing
    bw.close(); // you can omit this if you don't care about errors while closing
} catch (IOException e) {
    // error handling (e.g. on flushing)
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(bw);
}
```

`closeQuietly()` is not intended for general use instead of calling `close()` directly on a Closable. Its intended use-case is for ensuring the close inside a finally-block - all error handling you need have to be done BEFORE that.

That means, if you want to react on Exceptions during the call of `close()` or `flush()` then you've to handle it the normal way. Adding `closeQuietly()` in your finally-block just ensures the close, e.g. when the flush failed and close was not called in try-block.

Comment: I think bw.flush() is unnecessary, bw.close() calls flush() anyway

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev Yep, as long as you leave the `close()` in there. But when you only care about exceptions during flush but not close then you need to flush here explicitly. Just wrote both method calls to make the example a bit more universal.

Comment: Just to be clear: you *can* omit the call to `bw.close()` and bw will still be closed properly in the finally{} clause. Doing it this way also allows you to learn of any errors during `bw.close()`

Comment: `close()` doesn't always call `flush()` and sometimes `close()` calls flush but with the `IOException` masked in it.  See `FilterOutputStream` for example.

Answer (score 8):

It is safe so long as your application doesn't care whether the write succeeded without error. If your application needs to handle write errors it is not safe as [buffered data flushed on close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close%28%29) may be lost and the error swallowed.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's safe to use it but only for **Java6** and lower. From **Java7**, you should user [try-with-resource](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html).

It will eliminate much of the boilerplate code you have and the need to use `IOUtils.closeQuietly`.

Now, you example:

```
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));
    try {
        bw.write("test");
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(bw);
    }
```

Can be written as:

```
   try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"))) {
       bw.write("test");
   }
```

It's important to note that in order to use the try-with-resource approach, your resource need to implement a new interface called java.lang.AutoCloseable that was introduced in Java 7.

Also, you can include a number of resources in a try-with-resource block, just separate them with `;`

```
   try (
       BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test1.txt"));
       BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test2.txt"))
   ) {
       // Do something useful with those 2 buffers!
   }   // bw1 and bw2 will be closed in any case
```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible in theory but I can't say I have ever seen close() fail.  Usually fail fast means that a previous IO operations such as opening the file will fail first.  You can write a close which doesn't ignore IOExceptions but this could clobber the true cause of an exception if it is something in the try/catch block which failed.

What you want is something like the following (which is overkill in most cases)

```
try {
    // write to bw.
    bw.close(); // throw IOException if an error occurs.

} finally {
    // don't clobber a previous IOException
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(bw);
}
```

Comment: You are using it incorrectly - `IOUtils.closeQuietly()` is not intended for general use instead of calling close() directly on a Closable. Its intended use case is to ensure that close() is called  inside a finally block to avoid resource leak - all error handling (logging, exception wrapping and rethrowing) should be done BEFORE that -  see Fabian's answer

Comment: @JarekPrzygódzki When was the last time you saw an IOException on close specifically?

Comment: It's rare but it does happen - you never know what's behind the Closeable or {Input, Output}Stream. And silencing exceptions is almost never good.

Comment: I've examined the [source code](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) and read the documentation. `closeQuietly()` is little more than a call to `close()` surrounded by a try/catch that ignores exceptions. The documentation agrees. You **can** use `closeQuietly()` in place of close(), and the `finally{ }` block is the ideal place to do this.