# Should I use method close or closeQuietly to close an output stream?

Tags: java, outputstream

When we need close an output stream, we have two choices.

1. closeQuietly means close a stream with no exception throwing up.

   ```
   try {
       close(out)
   } catch(IOException e) {
   }
   ```
2. close

   ```
   try {
       close(out)
   } catch(IOException e) {
       throw anException;
   }
   ```

as known, output stream will write a/several chars into the end of file when closing, if these writing goes wrong, the file also can't be open correctly such as ZipoutputStream.

if I use the first one, I will get some risk of fail closing.
if I use the second one, it will let my code unfriendly.

Could someone give me some advices?

So sorry for describing the issue unclearly.

I meant that how to get an IO operation safely. if a resource's release gets failed, it would let caller know.

Thanks for all your answer. And especially thank @Don Roby for giving me a link which contains the best answer answered by @Fabian Barney

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it safe to use Apache commons-io IOUtils.closeQuietly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436453/is-it-safe-to-use-apache-commons-io-ioutils-closequietly)

Comment: `catch(IOException e) {    throw anException; }` is pointless - you'd need to declare `throws IOException` to do that, so you might as well skip the try/catch

Answer (score 17):

Since Java 7 `IOUtils.closeQuietly` became outdated and the only reasonable solution is `try-with-resources` which closes resources automatically

```
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
    ...
}
```

Note that it also solves problem with correctly opening / closing more than one resource

```
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(infile); OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outfile)) {
   ...          
}
```

And it also does not suppress IOException that `close()` may throw, which is exactly what `closeQuietly` does.

Answer (score 2):

Some implementations of `close()` may include other logic like writing final bytes or `flush()`'ing data. Example is `FilterOutputStream`.

Now imaging a situation when stream is based on network channel or external USB drive. Both may disappear at any time. It could happen when executing close().

So my opinion: catch IOException and throw your application-specific exception with included cause-exception, like:

```
} catch (IOException e)
{
    throw new IOManagementException(e);
}
```

If you are stick on not to throwing exception, then log if with ERROR status at least.

if not done, it may result in very hard to analyze bug reports or strange behavior.

Comment: it's a good answer, but it will let my code unfriendly. I have known another solution, it is that  try {..... out.close();} catch(IOException e) {throw a exception;} finally {IOUtils.closeQuietly(out)}

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, I never swallow exceptions, so depending on the logic required by the code I am writing, I might

1. Log the exception:

   ```
   try {
     close(out);
   } catch(IOException e) {
     // log the exception
     log.info("An error has occurred during stream closing: {}", e);
   }
   ```
2. Wrap it an throw it further

   ```
   try {
      close(out);
   } catch(IOException e) {
      throw new MyException(e);
   }
   ```

Since JDK 7 is around, I prefer (as mentioned by Evgeniy) to use try-with-resources:

```
try (OutputStream out = // create output stream) {
   // do the writing
} // at this point the stream is closed
```

This will close in an appropriate and safe manner the stream you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Clean code is good thing but where ever compromising it can give you better results like maintenance, Debugging in this case we should do that. It can be done in a better way like custom exception or using Java7 feature as suggested above but the cost of writing few more line is worth it as per my experience.