# Closing InputStream without a try/catch block?

Tags: java, inputstream

I know that an `InputStream` should be closed. But I have some doubts where and how to do this.

According to the documentation on [IOUtils.closeQuietly](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly(java.io.InputStream)):

> Unconditionally close an InputStream. Equivalent to
>   InputStream.close(), except any exceptions will be ignored. **This is
>   typically used in finally blocks**.

I don't need a `try/catch` block in my code so I don't have a `finally` block. Is it fine to just close the InputStream before returning it in my method below or should I do something differently? This method will be used by several services to load an `InputStream` from a file.

```
public InputStream read(String filename) {
    InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);

    if (inputStream == null) {
      // Throw some exception
    }

    IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);

    return inputStream;
}
```

Comment: Looking at your method, it shouldn't be the one to close the `InputStream`. Let the caller close it approprietly.

Comment: Why are you returning the `InputStream` and not the contents of the File?

Comment: @ndrone Because there is other logic that follows which needs the file as `InputStream`. But that isn't relevant for the question imo.

Comment: I guess I'm just trying to understand what good is a closed `InputSteam` is  to the other logic. But it looks like you found your answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);` at all in this method - there is very little point in returning a closed stream.

However, *this* method should be called in a try/finally block:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
  is = read(filename);
  // Do whatever with is.
} finally {
  IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
}
```

or with try-with-resources (noting the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436453/is-it-safe-to-use-apache-commons-io-ioutils-closequietly) that "try-with-resources statement will eliminate most needs for using `IOUtils.closeQuietly`"):

```
try (InputStream is = read(filename)) {
  // Do whatever with is.
}
```

Comment: I have multiple services that need to read an `InputStream` from a file which in turn needs to be mapped to some `Object` using `ObjectMapper`. I want separation of concerns (read from file, map to object) and I want to reuse logic. I could use an Abstract parent class, static Utility class whatever. My point is that my read method is not throwing an Exception at any point so I don't need a try/catch. Therefore I don't have a finally block in there. Should I still just surround it with a try/finally?

Comment: "my read method is not throwing an Exception at any point" Sure, maybe, now. What if you change the method? It's just best practice to remove the possibility of not closing a stream.

Comment: Thanks for the useful tips here. I'll refactor my code to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

try/finally block:

> InputStream is = null;
>          try {
>               InputStream is =
>               is = read(filename);
>               // Do whatever with is.
>               } finally {
>                  is.close();
>               }

Note: all i/o resources need to be closed in the finally block since it was initialized in the try-catch block. It is also advised to add:

```
} catch(IOException e){
   e.printstacktrace();
}
```

...for exception handling

Comment: Also forgot    ---       is.flush();